# Using IntelliJ IDE and Lua Programming Language to make Corona Applications

Tags: windows, lua, intellij-idea, coronasdk

I have successfully installed:

1) IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.3 with Lua Plugin
2) Corona SDK
3) Corona API for IntelliJ

I can now use autocompletion features of Lua and Corona using IntelliJ IDEA

Now my problem is :

When I try to run a sample main.lua script file using IntelliJ IDEA, i get this error

```
"C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua.exe" C:/Users/mshahab/IdeaProjects/TestOne/main.lua
C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua.exe: C:/Users/mshahab/IdeaProjects/TestOne/main.lua:1: attempt to index global 'display' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    C:/Users/mshahab/IdeaProjects/TestOne/main.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And when I run it (main.lua file) manually using the Corona Simulator it works fine. I am not sure what am I missing here ? Any pointers would be great :) Thanks

I am attaching the screenshot too 
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a good blog post that explains the setup

http://producerism.com/blog/how-to-develop-in-corona-sdk-on-windows/

Comment: ah yes ... I had to configure coronaSimulator.exe as a lua interpreter ... :) thanks for pointing to a great article :) ... And for your API's too for IntelliJ :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

> **"C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua.exe"** C:/Users/mshahab/IdeaProjects/TestOne/main.lua

This is running the file under vanilla Lua. Lua has no `display` library and your code isn't loading one.

> run it (main.lua file) manually using **the Corona Simulator**

You're running the script in a totally different app here, one that includes the `display` library. You need to configure IntelliJ to run Lua scripts via the simulator.

Comment: Yah I can run it manually :) ... How do i configure IntelliJ to run Lua scripts via the simulator ? :) please tell

Comment: Yes yes i found it :) the tutorial has configured the corona simulator :) my mistake thanks for the help